# WPF Application Freezing when getting Data and refreshing DataGrids

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a set of functions populating different DataGrids with EF objects similar to this:

```
var items = db.Items.AsNoTracking().Where(n => n.CategoryId == categoryId);
var grid = grdItems as DataGrid;
grid.ItemsSource = items;
```

The problem I have is that the window freezes i.e. cannot click or do anything until the above code is finished. Once finished, the grids are populated correctly so no issues there, but for the brief few seconds it appears to have crashed.

I wanted to add a simple loading type window/dialog so at least the UI displays something for the user than seeming like it has crashed. My problem is that adding a frm.Show, frm.Hide before/after this code above or trying to use a UserControl overlay, it never actually displays it because I expect the thread is busy.

I haven't been using WPF for very long and historically I used Forms where in cases like this I would use DoEvents but its my understanding this is likely to be more harmful than useful so I'm asking for the best possible way to update the UI with a loading overlay please. Particularly in the case of a DataGrid being populated and I expect any Converters/Vaildators being processed are contributing to the thread being busy.

Comment: I would make the database access async unless you know the data binding is taking up the time.  In regards to a loading window, you'll need another GUI thread (`STAThread` that pumps a message loop).

Answer (score 2):

You should either fetch the items asynchronously:

```
progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
var items = await db.Items.AsNoTracking().Where(n => n.CategoryId == categoryId)
    .ToListAsync();
progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

...or do it synchronously on a background thread:

```
var items = await Task.Run(() => db.Items.AsNoTracking()
    .Where(n => n.CategoryId == categoryId)
    .ToList());
```

See [Asynchronous programming with async and await](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/) for more information about asynchronous programming in C#.

Comment: What if the freeze is the items binding in the grid and not the data loading itself?

Comment: Then you need to either load fewer items or/and make sure that you haven't disabled the UI virtualization in the `DataGrid`.

Comment: Only around ten items being loaded. If I remove the code that sets the ItemsSource, it takes less than a second to process everything. I enabled row virtualization to check as well but this doesn't help the UI is stuck until its finished processing the grid. This is why I wanted a loading overlay, thoughts?

Comment: You need to provide a repo if you need any further help on this. Or ask a new question where you include your XAML markup as I believe the issue related to the code you have actually posted here has already been answered.

Comment: @R.Wood Your code just uses some LINQ to filter the items. LINQ executes all queries deferred to reduce the memory footprint. The following query doesn't return a result but an expression: `var items = db.Items.AsNoTracking().Where(n => n.CategoryId == categoryId)`. The query is actually executed when calling a conversion method like `ToList`, `Sum`, `First`, `foreach` etc. is invoked. Which is what the `DataGrid`does. This means `items` is just a query variable which actually holds the lazy query object.

Comment: @R.Wood Generally, when assigning an `IEnumerable` to an `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, the `ItemsContro` will iterate over the source collection in order to add the items to the underlying `ItemContainerGenerator`. This iteration (e.g. `foreach`) will call the `IEnumerator` of  the `IEnumerable`, which will execute any lazy LINQ query. Now passing the lazy object `item` to the `DataGrid`: `grid.ItemsSource = items` will force the `DataGrid` to execute the lazy query.

Comment: @R.Wood That's where you pay the performance penalty for passing a query to the UI: the UI will freeze until the query is executed and the grid rendered. The solution is to execute the query *before* you populate the `ItemsControl` (e.g. by calling `ToList`). The answer of @mm8 shows you exactly how to do this correctly without blocking the UI thread, which would cause a freeze. Read more about LINQ and lazy evaluation on [Microsoft Docs: Query Execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/query-execution).

Comment: @BionicCode thanks for the input, linq is used because I do more with the results before being assigned to the grid meaning the data has been loaded prior but I wanted to simplify code for the question. As per a comment above if I remove the ItemsSource binding there is no freeze or UI stick.

Comment: @R.Wood There is nothing wrong using LINQ. That's not the point. The point is that your actual code delegates the execution of the query to the `DataGrid` and because of this the execution is happening on the UI thread. When you execute the query asynchronously _before_  you assign it to the `DataGrid`, the freeze should disappear. I recommend the first solution of the above given examples. Just try it.

Comment: @R.Wood You can do your LINQ queries. Then the final line should be something like: `grid.ItemsSource = await items.ToListAsync()`;

Comment: @BionicCode Apologies think you missed what I was trying to say. I NEED to execute the query before assigning to the grid as I have to iterate the data for certain checks and functions beforehand. I think its likely to be converters that contribute than the data load

Comment: @R.Wood No need to apologize. Yes I understood you from the very beginning. I think  you may misunderstood the issue. LINQ is lazy evaluating your query: `db.Items.AsNoTracking().Where(n => n.CategoryId == categoryId)` does not immediately return a result. Only when you append a call to a conversion method like `ToList`, `ToListAsync` or iterate over it using `foreach`. _Then_ you get the filtered collection. Until this point the collection remains unfiltered (or the query not executed). Nothing will happen to the queried collection.

Comment: @R.Wood That's what is meant by deferred. You can pass the query around and add more queries to it. Only the first call to a conversion method will actually execute the query. We _want_ you to execute the query _BEFORE_ you assign anything to the `DataGrid`, but _asynchronously_, so that the query doesn't block the UI thread. Just try the code from the example or from my last comment `grid.ItemsSource = await items.ToListAsync();`. If you still don't understand, please read my comments again. if you still don't understand feel free to ask. But read my comments one more time, please.

Comment: @R.Wood The main point of interest is that LINQ doesn't execute immediately but _deferred_.

Comment: @R.Wood The reason why you won't experience any freeze when removing the binding is that the LINQ query is not executed (no conversion method call on the query chain) and the `DataGrid` is not busy executing the LINQ query (by using `foreach` internally).

Comment: @BionicCode I am using it in a foreach, I should have explained that when I said I was executing the query prior to grid assignment. The data is iterated and applied to a local List<> of objects that condenses down the information needed for the grid as well as converting/calculating certain fields accordingly for display. This happens in less than a second and the itemssource being set is the only time it freezes but its now a local list not a data entity anymore. This is why I feel the templatecolumns or converters are the contributing factor.

Comment: @BionicCode I didn't think all that was relevant when first asking the question so I feel I need to close this one and re-ask it with more detail and possibly find somewhere to post project for example

Comment: @R.Wood It's always good to post the full context of the problem and not what you think is important. As you may not understand the extend of problem, you would easily tend to rate details as unimportant although they ain't. You should also post the UI code to show how the `DataGrid` is templated. Also check the Output window for binding errors and enable all CLR exceptions. This kind of errors easily exist unnoticed, while they can slow down the UI drastically.

Answer (score 0):

Data access should really be performed using asynchronous calls away from the UI.

Typically this is done using a `Command` implementation (called from the UI) which in turn triggers off an `async Task`.

This `Task` can be used to set a Boolean flag to show that the system is busy, which in turn can be bound to indicate this to the user.

Comment: Do you have or can point me to an example? What if the freezing is due to the binding of the grid, converters etc